# Put binary numbers per row one by one

Tags: microsoft-excel, macros, microsoft-excel-2016, binary-files

My aim is convert decimal number to binary numbers and putting binary numbers one by one per column in EXCEL. I did convert decimal to binary using BASE command and do not know how to put it one by one in columns. Here is the picture that I want to do. How can I do it?

[image]

Comment: Simple curiosity? .. what on earth is the purpose of this?

Comment: @SeñorCMasMas Homework?

Answer (score 1):

You are aware of function DEC2BIN(cell).

```
 =BITAND($C4,2^G$3)/2^G$3
```

Cells G3 to Y3 have bits 15 to 0.

BITAND masks out relevant bit and division eliminates other bits.

[image]

Alternatively, you could have G3 to Y3 the multiples of 2 (1,2,4,8,16,32,etc).

```
 =BITAND($C4,G$3)/G$3
```